# NGINX: How to setup multiple port in one server or domain name?

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx. I am having trouble with my setup, I want my server to run with multiple port on public.

For example:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name <https - mydomainname>;
  ssl_certificate <location cert>;
  ssl_certificate_key <location key>;
    location /tags.txt {
      add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    }
}
```

From the above setup I am now able to access <https - mydomainname> perfectly. But what if I have http://localhost:6006 and http://localhost:5005 multiple ports in my localhost and I want to publish it. I tried to access it using this https - mydomainname : port 6006 and https - mydomainname : port 5005 but it fails.

Should I make a setup for another port?
Like for port 6006

```
server {
 listen 6006 ssl;
 server_name <https - mydomainname>;
 ssl_certificate <location cert>;
 ssl_certificate_key <location key>;
  location /tags.txt {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:6006;
  }
}
```

and port 5005

```
server {
 listen 5005 ssl;
 server_name <https - mydomainname>;
 ssl_certificate <location cert>;
 ssl_certificate_key <location key>;
  location /tags.txt {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5005;
  }
}
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can have multiple `listen` directives per `server`:

```
server {
 listen 5005 ssl;
 listen 6006 ssl;
 server_name <https - mydomainname>;
 ssl_certificate <location cert>;
 ssl_certificate_key <location key>;
  location /tags.txt {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, I tried it already and says "This site can’t be reached", But when I try to access using the public IP (ex. 54.22.4.88:6006) the site is running well.

Comment: Do i need to write this in https server block in the nginx configuration file?