# NGINX: Setup SSL Certificate for multiple ports for proxy pass

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-config

I am new to nginx and have a scenario where I need to listen to two https port and after authentication redirect to proxy pass to internal streamlit url. I am able to browse to
*https://<domainname*> but not *https://domainname:8877*

I tried to do the same as tried in this [NGINX: Setup SSL Certificate for multiple ports using 1 domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50591202/nginx-setup-ssl-certificate-for-multiple-ports-using-1-domain-name)

Following is my nginx.conf file

```
 server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name  <domain name> default_server;


        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/self.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/self.key;
            # Disable SSL
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    # Optimise cipher suits
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    # Enable DH Params
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # Enable HSTS
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    # SSL sessions
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:40m;
        ssl_session_timeout 4h;
        ssl_session_tickets on;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # streamlit specific
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        location / {
            auth_basic "Access Restricted";
            auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8501/;
}
}

server {
        listen 8877 ssl http2;
        listen [::]:8877 ssl;
        server_name  <domain name> .com;


        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/self.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/self.key;
            # Disable SSL
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    # Optimise cipher suits
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    # Enable DH Params
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # Enable HSTS
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

    # SSL sessions
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:40m;
        ssl_session_timeout 4h;
        ssl_session_tickets on;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # streamlit specific
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 86400;

        location / {
#            auth_basic "Access Restricted";
#            auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/seconduser/.htpasswd";
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8502/;
        }
```