# I want to link different ports of the same IP address to my instance so that when I type it in my address bar it shows my webpage, how to do that?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, load-balancing

I want to load balance using nginx, using different ports of the same ip address. But, I can't understand how to link the different ports to the same instance. I'm using an ec2 instance on AWS. I want to access the instance through different ports example 8000, 8001

My biggest question is how do I start a process on a specific port?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K63I7.png)

I want to duplicate my process running on 8000 t0 8001, 8002, 8003 so IN can load balance. 
Already enabled inbound rules on AWS

Answer (score 0):

Put two `listen PORT;` directives inside your `server` block.
Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38054382/3375252